# Fatal error in PMPI_Send: Invalid tag, error stack: MPI_Send(

Tags: fortran, mpi, intel-mpi

I am using MPI to parallelise my Fortran code. The code below is the parellelisation part. I use 2 nodes to run the program.

```
1     DO i = 1, km(1), 1
2        DO j = 1, km(2), 1
3           DO k = 1, km(3), 1
4              IF (MOD((i-1)*km(2)*km(3)+(j-1)*km(3)+k-1, world_size) /= world_rank) CYCLE
5              CALL TRANSPORT(i,j,k,dk,ra,lz,iy,ch,nm,te,nb,po,tv,lr,ei,ks,ol,vm,t2,t3)
6              IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
7                 c2 = c2 + t2
8                 c4 = c4 + t3
9                 DO l = 1, world_size-1, 1
10                   IF ((i-1)*km(2)*km(3)+(j-1)*km(3)+k-1+l == km(1)*km(2)*km(2)) EXIT
11                   m = (i-1)*km(2)*km(3)+(j-1)*km(3)+k + l + 100000
12                   CALL MPI_RECV(c3,nm,MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,l,m,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE,ierr)
13                   c2 = c2 + c3
14                   n = (i-1)*km(2)*km(3)+(j-1)*km(3)+k + l + 1000000
15                   CALL MPI_RECV(c5,nm,MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,l,n,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE,ierr)
16                   c4 = c4 + c5
17                END DO
18             ELSE
19                m = (i-1)*km(2)*km(3)+(j-1)*km(3)+k + 100000
20                CALL MPI_SEND(t2,nm,MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,0,m,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
21                n = (i-1)*km(2)*km(3)+(j-1)*km(3)+k + 1000000
22                CALL MPI_SEND(t3,nm,MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,0,n,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
23             END IF
24          END DO
25       END DO
26    END DO
27    print*,'before final'
28    CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
29    print*,'after final'
```

What I found is that if the variables are 'km(1)=1, km(2)=1 and km(3)=2', the calculation could be done successfully; while, if the variables are 'km(1)=2, km(2)=2 and km(3)=1', the program can only outputs 'before final' on the 27th line and cannot output 'after final' on the 29th line.

It prints

```
 before final
 before final
Abort(604623620) on node 1 (rank 1 in comm 0): Fatal error in PMPI_Send: Invalid tag, error stack:
PMPI_Send(157): MPI_Send(buf=0x7ffd802631c0, count=100, MPI_DOUBLE, dest=0, tag=1000002, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
PMPI_Send(95).: Invalid tag, value is 1000002
```

In other words, my code is stuck at the 'CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)' command on the 28th line.

The reason why I added 28th line is because I want to output the 'c2' and 'c4' arrays after all process finishes the program. Would anyone please tell me why the code is stuck on the 28th line and how to resolve it? Thank you very much.

This is a simple reproducible code, which has the same structure as my original Fortran code. Would you please have a look at it and give me some suggestions? Thank you.

```
SUBROUTINE SUBROUT(i,j,k,t2,t3)
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp=SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15,14)
INTEGER            :: i, j, k
REAL (KIND=dp)     :: t2(100), t3(100)
INTEGER            :: l, m, n

m = i*10+j*12+k-3
n = i*11+j-3+k*15

DO l = 1, 100, 1
   t2(l) = DBLE(l)+DBLE(m)
   t3(l) = DBLE(l)+DBLE(n)
END DO

RETURN
END SUBROUTINE SUBROUT

PROGRAM TEST
USE MPI
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp=SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15,14)
INTEGER            :: i, j, k, l, m, n, km(3)
REAL (KIND=dp)     :: t2(100), t3(100), c2(100), c3(100), c4(100), c5(100)
INTEGER            :: world_size, world_rank, ierr

CALL MPI_INIT(ierr)
CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,world_size,ierr)
CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,world_rank,ierr)

km(1) = 1
km(2) = 1
km(3) = 2

DO i = 1, km(1), 1
   DO j = 1, km(2), 1
      DO k = 1, km(3), 1
         IF (MOD((i-1)*km(2)*km(3)+(j-1)*km(3)+k-1, world_size) /= world_rank) CYCLE
         CALL SUBROUT(i,j,k,t2,t3)
         IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
            c2 = c2 + t2
            c4 = c4 + t3
            DO l = 1, world_size-1, 1
               IF ((i-1)*km(2)*km(3)+(j-1)*km(3)+k-1+l == km(1)*km(2)*km(2)) EXIT
               m = (i-1)*km(2)*km(3)+(j-1)*km(3)+k + l + 100000
               CALL MPI_RECV(c3,100,MPI_DOUBLE,l,m,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE,ierr)
               c2 = c2 + c3
               n = (i-1)*km(2)*km(3)+(j-1)*km(3)+k + l + 1000000
               CALL MPI_RECV(c5,100,MPI_DOUBLE,l,n,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE,ierr)
               c4 = c4 + c5
            END DO
         ELSE
            m = (i-1)*km(2)*km(3)+(j-1)*km(3)+k + 100000
            CALL MPI_SEND(t2,100,MPI_DOUBLE,0,m,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
            n = (i-1)*km(2)*km(3)+(j-1)*km(3)+k + 1000000
            CALL MPI_SEND(t3,100,MPI_DOUBLE,0,n,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
         END IF
      END DO
   END DO
END DO
print*,'before final'
CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
print*,'after final'

IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
    WRITE (UNIT=*, FMT=*) c2
    WRITE (UNIT=*, FMT=*) c4
END IF

CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)

STOP
END PROGRAM TEST
```

This is my script file for job submission.

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH --partition=3080ti
#SBATCH --job-name=test
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=12

module load compiler/2022.0.2
module load mkl/2022.0.2
module load mpi/2021.5.1
mpirun ./test
```

This is my compiling file.

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH --partition=cpu
#SBATCH --job-name=qt
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1

module load compiler/2022.0.2
module load mkl/2022.0.2
module load mpi/2021.5.1

mpiifort -qmkl -coarray -fp-model strict -no-wrap-margin -g -traceback -check test.f90 -o test
```

Comment: Try using a debugger and check where the individual processes are. The `-pid`  flag in `gdb` is helpful. Typically, you have a deadlock when one or often two processes are receiving but no one sending anything to them or when they are sending, but no one is receiving from them.

Comment: If you want more helo, create a [mcve], please, and explain what it is actually doing. But the information from the debugger is crucial. Don't forget to compile your code with the `-g` flag.

Comment: did you double check `km(1:3)` is the same on all the ranks? also, you can double check `world_rank` has the right value (and never gets overwritten)

Comment: To avoid deadlocks you have to be very careful in which order you issue the sends and the receives in each process. The non-blocking ISend and IRecv is often helpful with a wall placed MPI_Wait.

Comment: Also, please do not add those line numbers to your code snippets. These are not the actual line numbers in your source files and will not correspond to any debugger messages. They make it only more complicated to people who may want to copy your code and test it, but they are not helpful in any way.

Comment: @Vladimir I update my question with a simple reproducible code, which has the same strucutre as my origianl FORTRAN code. I had already added -g in my compiling file and the code could be compiled successfully without any error message but it seems to be stuck when it was ran. Would you please give me some suggestions for the solution? Thank you.

Comment: @Gilles I update my question with a simple reproducible code, which has the same strucutre as my origianl FORTRAN code. The variables 'km(1:3)' are same on all process. However, the reproducible code seems to be stuck. Would you please give me some suggestions on the solution? Thank you.

Comment: how many mpi tasks do you run? with `-np 2`, the program completes.

Comment: Please note it is officially spelt Fortran and has been for over 30 years

Comment: @Gilles I update my question with my script file for job submission and a compiling file. Would you please have a look at them? Thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: OK, now I can reproduce your problem; (but you could have told us all the error messages).  The larger of your two tags is too big ("PMPI_Send(95).: Invalid tag, value is 1000002"). It is smaller than MPI_TAG_UB, but, sadly, that doesn't mean your system will accept it. If you knock a couple of zeroes off your second tag (why exactly do you need it to be that big?) then it will probably run. Problem occurred with mpiifort but not with gfortran plus MS-MPI.

Comment: Yes, the limits for the tag number vary widely among MPI implementations. I used to be fine with OpenMPI and MPICH on small clusters until I tried Cray MPI on ARCHER. Some could make the mistake of including unnecessary distinguishing information into the tag. E.g., the ranks of the sender and the receiver do not have to be included, they are a part of the envelope. But I would never understand *"In other words, my code is stuck at ... on the 28th line."* as a this kind of error. "the program is stuck" means that it hangs forever. When there is an error message, it **must** be reported.

Comment: @lastchance Thank you for the explanation. Previously, I did not realize that the tag value has the upper bonding limit so I just set it as a large value. I will try the smaller tag value.

Comment: @Vladimir Thank you for the explanation. I will be careful when I write my question next time and try to state my problem in a clear and accurate way to other readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's alluded to by Vladimir in

> Some could make the mistake of including unnecessary distinguishing information into the tag. E.g., the ranks of the sender and the receiver do not have to be included, they are a part of the envelope.

but not mentioned explicitly: if you can find just one tag value, the simplest being 0, that's not also used in an asynchronous fashion, it's okay to just skip the calculation of m and n and simply use 0 in their place. This assumes rank 0 "knows" what data will be computed by each rank but in most programs that's indeed the case.

Simplifying your program to

```
    SUBROUTINE SUBROUT(i,j,k,t2,t3)
      IMPLICIT NONE
      INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp=SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15,14)
      INTEGER            :: i, j, k
      REAL (KIND=dp)     :: t2(100), t3(100)
      INTEGER            :: l, m, n

      m = i*10+j*12+k-3
      n = i*11+j-3+k*15

      DO l = 1, 100, 1
         t2(l) = DBLE(l)+DBLE(m)
         t3(l) = DBLE(l)+DBLE(n)
      END DO

      RETURN
    END SUBROUTINE SUBROUT

    PROGRAM TEST
      USE MPI
      IMPLICIT NONE
      INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp=SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15,14)
      INTEGER            :: i, j, k, l, km(3)
      REAL (KIND=dp)     :: t2(100), t3(100), c2(100), c3(100), c4(100), c5(100)
      INTEGER            :: world_size, world_rank, ierr

      CALL MPI_INIT(ierr)
      CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,world_size,ierr)
      CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,world_rank,ierr)

      km(1) = 1
      km(2) = 1
      km(3) = 2

      DO i = 1, km(1), 1
         DO j = 1, km(2), 1
            DO k = 1, km(3), 1
               IF (MOD((i-1)*km(2)*km(3)+(j-1)*km(3)+k-1, world_size) /= world_rank) CYCLE
               CALL SUBROUT(i,j,k,t2,t3)
               IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
                  c2 = c2 + t2
                  c4 = c4 + t3
                  DO l = 1, world_size-1, 1
                     IF ((i-1)*km(2)*km(3)+(j-1)*km(3)+k-1+l == km(1)*km(2)*km(2)) EXIT
                     CALL      MPI_RECV(c3,100,MPI_DOUBLE,l,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE,ierr)
                     c2 = c2 + c3
                     CALL      MPI_RECV(c5,100,MPI_DOUBLE,l,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE,ierr)
                     c4 = c4 + c5
                  END DO
               ELSE
                  CALL MPI_SEND(t2,100,MPI_DOUBLE,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
                  CALL MPI_SEND(t3,100,MPI_DOUBLE,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
               END IF
            END DO
         END DO
      END DO
      print*,'before final'
      CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
      print*,'after final'


      IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
          WRITE (UNIT=*, FMT=*) c2
          WRITE (UNIT=*, FMT=*) c4
      END IF
 
      CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)

      STOP
    END PROGRAM TEST
```

should result in something that works on many MPI implementations, at least with respect to the message passing and assuming that the effective MPI_Reduce does not overwhelm the network. MPI_Reduce is probably also the next routine you should read up on.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Would you please give me another example that 'rank 0' does not know what data other ranks send and setting up the variable 'tag' is necessary?

Comment: Essentially when rank 0 "knows" that some data item will be computed but doesn't necessarily know the sender rank. That could be the result of some dynamic load balancing scheme, where other ranks swap tasks to work on (sort of actor model). But in the case of your program that's not the case, so no need to worry, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

The maximum value of a tag guaranteed by the MPI specification is only 32767. The individual MPI implementations may allow more, but do not have to.

You can find out the maximum possible tag value by calling `MPI_Comm_get_attr` with key `MPI_TAG_UB`. A warning: `MPI_TAG_UB` is only a key for the call to get the value of the attribute, not the value of the attribute itself!

```
use mpi

integer :: comm, max_tag, flag, ierr
comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD
call MPI_Comm_get_attr(comm, MPI_TAG_UB, max_tag, flag, ierr)

print *, flag
print *, max_tag
```

Notice that the value may depend on the communicator. With bigger communicators the limit may be more strict. See [Large MPI Tags with the Intel® MPI Library](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/large-mpi-tags-with-the-intel-mpi.html) for more.

But the simplest solution is avoid querying and just use values below 32767.

Comment: FWIW, the tag's upper bound can depend on the interconnect that is used, so it might not be the same if running the same app with the same MPI library on one or multiple nodes.